# If I have a line from point x1, y1 to x2, y2, how can I draw 2 lines coming from point x2, y2 at 45 degree angles to make an arrow?

Tags: c++, math, geometry

I want an arrow to be drawn from the point the user clicks the mouse to the point he drags it to. The base line is the first line drawn in the code below. Now I would like 2 more short lines of distance d lines coming out of that point at 45 degrees to create an arrow pointing to the current mouse position. Those two lines are the second 2 lines drawn. drawLine() draws a line from the point at the first 2 values to the point at the 2nd 2 values. What I can't figure out is how to calculate the coordinates of the arrowLine variables I have in the code below.

```
    double deltaX = mousePosX - mouseOnDownX;
    double deltaY = mousePosY - mouseOnDownY;
    double distance = sqrt(pow(deltaX, 2) + pow(deltaY, 2));
    double angle = atan(deltaY / deltaX) * 180 / PI;
    int arrowLineLength = 20;
    int arrowLineAngle = 45;
    screen->drawLine(mousePosX, mousePosY, mouseOnDownX,mouseOnDownY);
    screen->drawLine(mousePosX, mousePosY, arrowLine1x,arrowLine1y);
    screen->drawLine(mousePosX, mousePosY, arrowLine2x,arrowLine2y);
```

EDIT: To clarify, mouseOnDownX and mouseOnDownY are the coordinates of the mouse when the user originally presses the mouse button. mousePosX and mousePosY are the coordinates of the mouse at it's current position and is the point the arrow head lines should be coming out of.

Comment: this is co-ordinate geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

co-ordinates are:

```
arrowLine1x=x+d*cos(atan(deltaY/deltaX)+45);
arrowLine1y=y+d*sin(atan(deltaY/deltaX)+45);
arrowLine2x=x+d*cos(atan(deltaY/deltaX)-45);
arrowLine2y=y+d*sin(atan(deltaY/deltaX)-45);
```

Comment: What is the meaning of "d"?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a vector pointed in some direction and you want to rotate it clockwise by θ degrees, you can multiply it by this matrix:

```
 |cos θ    -sin θ|
 |sin θ     cos θ|
```

Therefore, if you have a direction vector pointing as (dx, dy), the vector formed by rotating it θ degrees clockwise is

```
dx' = dx cos θ - dy sin θ
dy' = dx sin θ + dy cos θ
```

In your case, you have a vector from the source to the destination. Therefore, a vector from the destination to the source would be given by `(-deltaX, -deltaY)`. You can then get vectors 45 degrees to the left and right of this by plugging things into the above formula:

```
dx' = -deltaX cos θ + deltaY sin θ
dy' = -deltaX sin θ - deltaY cos θ
```

Use θ = π / 4 and θ = -π / 4 to get the 45° rotations in each direction. To ensure that the length of the line you draw is exactly d, you can normalize these vectors, then multiply by d. For example:

```
finalDX = dx' * d / sqrt(dx'^2 + dy'^2)
finalDY = dy' * d / sqrt(dx'^2 + dy'^2)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't you mean π / 4? So that cos θ = sin θ = sqrt(2)/2?